# UIButton not clickable until I scroll down

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSDictionary * startup = [self.entries objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

CLLocationDistance distance = 0;

float miles = 0;

NSDictionary * val;
if([startup objectForKey: @"startup"] &&
   [startup objectForKey: @"startup"] != (id) [NSNull null]) {

    val = [startup objectForKey: @"startup"];
}
else {

    val = startup;
}

if ([startup objectForKey: @"longitude"] &&
    [startup objectForKey: @"longitude"] != (id)[NSNull null] &&
    [startup objectForKey: @"latitude"] &&
    [startup objectForKey: @"latitude"] != (id)[NSNull null] )
{

    CLLocationDegrees latitude = [[startup objectForKey: @"latitude"] doubleValue];
    CLLocationDegrees longitude = [[startup objectForKey: @"longitude"] doubleValue];

    distance = [self myDistanceFromLatitude: latitude longitude: longitude];
    miles = [self convertToMiles: distance];
}

NSString * photo_url = @"";
NSString * funding_t = @"n/a";
NSString * pitch = @"";
NSString * name = @"";
NSInteger startup_id;
NSString * team_size = @"0";
NSString * revenue = @"";
NSString * raising = @"";
NSString * category = @"n/a";
NSArray * categories1;

if ([val objectForKey: @"current_funding"] &&
    [val objectForKey: @"current_funding"] != (id)[NSNull null])
{
    funding_t = [val objectForKey: @"current_funding"];
}

if ([val objectForKey: @"pitch"] &&
    [val objectForKey: @"pitch"] != (id)[NSNull null])
{
    pitch = [val objectForKey: @"pitch"];
}

if ([val objectForKey: @"name"] &&
    [val objectForKey: @"name"] != (id)[NSNull null])
{
    name = [val objectForKey: @"name"];
}

if ([val objectForKey: @"id"] &&
    [val objectForKey: @"id"] != (id)[NSNull null])
{
    if ([[val objectForKey: @"id"] intValue] > 0)
    {
        startup_id = [[val objectForKey: @"id"] intValue];
    }
}

if ([val objectForKey: @"team_size"] &&
    [val objectForKey: @"team_size"] != (id)[NSNull null])
{
    if ([[val objectForKey: @"team_size"] intValue] > 0)
    {
        team_size = [[val objectForKey: @"team_size"] stringValue];
    }
}

if ([val objectForKey: @"round_raising"] &&
    [val objectForKey: @"round_raising"] != (id)[NSNull null])
{
    raising = [val objectForKey: @"round_raising"];
}

if ([val objectForKey: @"revenue"] &&
    [val objectForKey: @"revenue"] != (id)[NSNull null])
{
    revenue = [val objectForKey: @"revenue"];
}

if ([val objectForKey: @"categories"] &&
    [val objectForKey: @"categories"] != (id)[NSNull null])
{
    categories1 = [val objectForKey: @"categories"];

    if([categories1 count] >= 1)
    {
        category = [[categories1 objectAtIndex: 0] objectForKey: @"name"];
    }
}

if ([val objectForKey: @"photo_url"] &&
    [val objectForKey: @"photo_url"] != (id)[NSNull null])
{
    photo_url = [val objectForKey: @"photo_url"];
}

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(308, 175);


static NSString *cellID = @"Cell Identifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellID];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];

    UIImage * box = [UIImage imageNamed: @"box.png"];
    UIView * cellbackgroundview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(7, 0, box.size.width, box.size.height)];
    [cellbackgroundview setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: box]];

    UILabel * nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 0, 15, box.size.width, 19.0f)];
    nameLabel.text = name;
    [nameLabel setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0f/255.0f green:79.0f/255.0f blue:79.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    [nameLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size: 18.0f]];
    [nameLabel setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
    nameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    nameLabel.tag = 1;

    UILabel * pitchLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 0, 40, box.size.width, 14.0f)];
    pitchLabel.text = pitch;
    pitchLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [pitchLabel setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0f/255.0f green:79.0f/255.0f blue:79.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    [pitchLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Light" size: 12.0f]];
    [pitchLabel setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
    pitchLabel.tag = 2;

    UIImageView * midview;
    midview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(-3, 64, 308, 175)];
    midview.tag = 3;
    midview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gotodeck:)];
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [midview addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

    UIImage * play = [UIImage imageNamed: @"nearby_play.png"];
    UIImageView * playview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(120, 120, play.size.width, play.size.height)];
    [playview setImage: play];

    [cellbackgroundview addSubview: nameLabel];
    [cellbackgroundview addSubview: pitchLabel];
    [cellbackgroundview addSubview: midview];
    [cellbackgroundview addSubview: playview];


    float lwidth = (box.size.width - 10) / 3;
    float toppos1 =  box.size.height - 43;

    UIImage * limg = [UIImage imageNamed: @"like.png"];

    UIButton * likebtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [likebtn setImage: limg forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [likebtn setTitleColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 174.0f/255.0f green: 174.0f/255.0f blue: 174.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [likebtn.titleLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size: 14.0f]];
    [likebtn addTarget:self action:@selector(like:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    likebtn.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    likebtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    likebtn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 20);
    [likebtn setTitle: @"Like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    likebtn.tag = 4;
    likebtn.frame = CGRectMake(15, toppos1, lwidth, 40);

    UIImage * limg1 = [UIImage imageNamed: @"chatbox.png"];
    UIButton * chatbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [chatbtn setTitleColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 174.0f/255.0f green: 174.0f/255.0f blue: 174.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [chatbtn setImage: limg1 forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [chatbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(chat:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    chatbtn.tag = 5;
    chatbtn.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    chatbtn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 20);
    [chatbtn.titleLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size: 14.0f]];
    [chatbtn setTitle: @"Chat" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    chatbtn.frame = CGRectMake(likebtn.frame.origin.x + likebtn.frame.size.width, toppos1, lwidth, 40);


    UIImage * limg2 = [UIImage imageNamed: @"share.png"];
    UIButton * sharebtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [sharebtn setImage: limg2 forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [sharebtn setTitleColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 174.0f/255.0f green: 174.0f/255.0f blue: 174.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [sharebtn.titleLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size: 14.0f]];
    [sharebtn addTarget:self action:@selector(share:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    sharebtn.tag = 6;
    sharebtn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 20);
    [sharebtn setTitle: @"Share" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    sharebtn.frame = CGRectMake(chatbtn.frame.origin.x + chatbtn.frame.size.width, toppos1, lwidth, 40);


    float width = (box.size.width - 10)/3;
    float toppos = midview.frame.origin.y + midview.frame.size.height + 10;

    UILabel * aLabel3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 13,
                                                                   toppos,
                                                                   width,
                                                                   20)];
    aLabel3.text = @"Industry";
    [aLabel3 setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0f/255.0f green: 79.0f/255.0f blue: 79.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    aLabel3.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    aLabel3.frame = CGRectIntegral(aLabel3.frame);
    [aLabel3 setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Light" size: 14.0f]];
    aLabel3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    UILabel * aLabel4 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( aLabel3.frame.origin.x + aLabel3.frame.size.width,  toppos, width, 20)];
    aLabel4.text = @"Funding";
    [aLabel4 setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0f/255.0f green: 79.0f/255.0f blue: 79.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    aLabel4.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    aLabel4.frame = CGRectIntegral(aLabel4.frame);
    [aLabel4 setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Light" size: 14.0f]];
    aLabel4.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];



    UILabel * aLabel5 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( aLabel4.frame.origin.x + aLabel4.frame.size.width,  toppos, width, 20)];
    aLabel5.text = @"Revenue";
    aLabel5.frame = CGRectIntegral(aLabel5.frame);
    [aLabel5 setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0f/255.0f green: 79.0f/255.0f blue: 79.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    aLabel5.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [aLabel5 setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Light" size: 14.0f]];
    aLabel5.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    float width2 = width;

    UILabel * aLabel3a = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( aLabel3.frame.origin.x,  aLabel3.frame.origin.y + aLabel3.frame.size.height + 5, width2, 20)];
    aLabel3a.text = category;
    [aLabel3a setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0f/255.0f green: 79.0f/255.0f blue: 79.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    aLabel3a.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    aLabel3a.frame = CGRectIntegral(aLabel3a.frame);
    aLabel3a.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    aLabel3a.tag = 7;
    [aLabel3a setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size: 14.0f]];
    aLabel3a.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel * aLabel4a = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( aLabel3a.frame.origin.x + aLabel3a.frame.size.width, aLabel3.frame.origin.y + aLabel3.frame.size.height + 5, width2, 20)];
    aLabel4a.text = funding_t;
    aLabel4a.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    aLabel4a.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    aLabel4a.frame = CGRectIntegral(aLabel4a.frame);
    aLabel4a.tag = 8;
    [aLabel4a setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0f/255.0f green: 79.0f/255.0f blue: 79.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    [aLabel4a setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size: 14.0f]];
    aLabel4a.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel * aLabel5a = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( aLabel4a.frame.origin.x + aLabel4a.frame.size.width,  aLabel3.frame.origin.y + aLabel3.frame.size.height + 5, width2, 20)];
    aLabel5a.text = revenue;
    [aLabel5a setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0f/255.0f green: 79.0f/255.0f blue: 79.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    aLabel5a.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    aLabel5a.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    aLabel5a.tag = 9;
    aLabel5a.frame = CGRectIntegral(aLabel5a.frame);
    [aLabel5a setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size: 14.0f]];
    aLabel5a.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    UIImage * rimg = [UIImage imageNamed: @"ribbon.png"];
    UIView * rview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(box.size.width - 48, -3, rimg.size.width, rimg.size.height)];
    [rview setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: rimg]];

    UILabel * disLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 10, rimg.size.width, 16)];
    disLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    disLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [disLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size: 14.0f]];
    disLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    disLabel.tag = 10;
    disLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [rview addSubview: disLabel];

    UILabel * disLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, disLabel.frame.size.height - 5, rimg.size.width, rimg.size.height)];
    disLabel2.text = @"miles";
    disLabel2.numberOfLines = 0;
    disLabel2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [disLabel2 setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Light" size: 12.0f]];
    disLabel2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    disLabel2.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [rview addSubview: disLabel2];

    /*
    UIImage * progress = [UIImage imageNamed: @"progressback.png"];
    UIImageView * progressimg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: progress];
    progressimg.frame = CGRectMake(aLabel3.frame.origin.x + 12, aLabel3a.frame.origin.y + aLabel3a.frame.size.height + 15, progress.size.width, progress.size.height);


    UILabel * aLabel3b = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( progressimg.frame.origin.x - 10,  progressimg.frame.origin.y + progressimg.frame.size.height + 15, width, 20)];
    aLabel3b.text = @"Investors";
    [aLabel3b setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0f/255.0f green: 79.0f/255.0f blue: 79.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    aLabel3b.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [aLabel3b setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Light" size: 14.0f]];
    aLabel3b.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];




    UILabel * aLabel4b = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( aLabel3b.frame.origin.x + aLabel3b.frame.size.width, aLabel3b.frame.origin.y, width, 20)];
    aLabel4b.text = @"Raising";
    [aLabel4b setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0f/255.0f green: 79.0f/255.0f blue: 79.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    aLabel4b.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [aLabel4b setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Light" size: 14.0f]];
    aLabel4b.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];



    UILabel * aLabel5b = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( aLabel4b.frame.origin.x + aLabel4b.frame.size.width, aLabel3b.frame.origin.y, width, 20)];
    aLabel5b.text = @"Team";
    [aLabel5b setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0f/255.0f green: 79.0f/255.0f blue: 79.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    aLabel5b.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [aLabel5b setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Light" size: 14.0f]];
    aLabel5b.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel * aLabel3ab = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( aLabel3b.frame.origin.x,  aLabel3b.frame.origin.y + aLabel3b.frame.size.height + 5, width2, 20)];
    aLabel3ab.text = @"Mobile App";
    [aLabel3ab setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0f/255.0f green: 79.0f/255.0f blue: 79.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    aLabel3ab.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [aLabel3ab setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size: 14.0f]];
    aLabel3ab.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    UILabel * aLabel4ab = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( aLabel3ab.frame.origin.x + aLabel3ab.frame.size.width,  aLabel3b.frame.origin.y + aLabel3b.frame.size.height + 5, width2, 20)];
    aLabel4ab.text = @"Funding";
    aLabel4ab.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [aLabel4ab setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0f/255.0f green: 79.0f/255.0f blue: 79.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    [aLabel4ab setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size: 14.0f]];
    aLabel4ab.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];



    UILabel * aLabel5ab = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( aLabel4a.frame.origin.x + aLabel4a.frame.size.width,  aLabel3b.frame.origin.y + aLabel3b.frame.size.height + 5, width2, 20)];
    aLabel5ab.text = team_size;
    [aLabel5ab setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0f/255.0f green: 79.0f/255.0f blue: 79.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    aLabel5ab.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [aLabel5ab setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size: 14.0f]];
    aLabel5ab.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    */

    [cell.contentView addSubview: cellbackgroundview];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: aLabel3];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: aLabel4];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: aLabel5];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: aLabel3a];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: aLabel4a];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: aLabel5a];


    /*
     [cell addSubview: progressimg];
     [cell addSubview: aLabel3b];
     [cell addSubview: aLabel4b];
     [cell addSubview: aLabel5b];
     [cell addSubview: aLabel3ab];
     [cell addSubview: aLabel4ab];
     [cell addSubview: aLabel5ab];
     */

    [cell.contentView addSubview: rview];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: likebtn];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: chatbtn];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: sharebtn];

}

((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1]).text = name;
((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2]).text = pitch;
((UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:4]).tag = startup_id;
((UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:5]).tag = indexPath.row;
((UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:6]).tag = indexPath.row;
((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:7]).text = category;
((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:8]).text = funding_t;
((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:9]).text = revenue;
((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10]).text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%1.1f", miles];

if(photo_url.length >= 1)
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: photo_url];
    [((UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:3]) setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_startup_img"]];
    [((UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:3]).image imageCroppedToFitSize: newSize];
}
else {
    [((UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:3]) setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"default_startup_img"]];
}
((UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:3]).tag = indexPath.row;


return cell;
```

}

Comment: can you show method cellForRowAtIndexPath fully?

Comment: I edited the question to show the full code.

Comment: try comment line [midview addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with UITableView not being tappable until I scroll UITableView down - I have noticed that after I added NSNotification to update the table once all of images are download in download manager. I was updating my table view using [_tableview realoadData];

I realised that I was doing a very simple mistake - reloadData was not really called on main thread. Once I did

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

instead of

```
[_categoryTableView reloadData];
```

UITableView getting stuck issue gone.

I am not sure if this is exactly problem of @Rue Vitale , but if I cam across this topic while looking for origin of my issue, I thought it's worth sharing.

Comment: I was having an issue with a tableView not being selectable until I dragged it. This definitely led me on the right path. Though I would use: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
});

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you create buttons but you should make something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"buttonsCell";

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

your code...        

    }

    return cell;
}
```